# Can't find the download center at the mobilefirst operation console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-console

When I run the MobileFirst Operation by right clicking the MF project on Eclipse and then selecting the , like so:

[image: Like so]

I get a Operation Console site but different from the ones I find on the internet. In this site I can't find the download center.

Does anybody know what I did wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The Download Center in the MobileFirst Operations Console that you are talking about is part of **MobileFirst Foundation 8.0**, whereas what you are using is **MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.x**.

What you are using in the screen shot is MobileFirst Studio for MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1. In MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 there is no longer a studio component as you may be accustomed to.

Instead, in v8.0 what you need to do is to either download the Developer Kit which will extract a pre-configured Liberty server with MobileFirst Server deployed to it, in which case after starting it and visiting the console, you will then see the downloads center you are looking for.

Or, instead of downloading the DevKit, you can start a server instance on IBM Bluemix.

- To download the DevKit, visit here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/downloads/

  Then follow the instructions on how to start the server, etc. You are more then encouraged to read the docs, here: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/all-tutorials/
- To start a server instance on Bluemix, first create an account on [Bluemix.net](https://bluemix.net) and then read this doc on how to start a server instance: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/bluemix/using-mobile-foundation/